# Как при срабатывании условия добавлять виджет на страницу сайта Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть алгоритм, а так же сервер на фласке, для удобного управления. И у меня появилась нужда в добавлении например контейнера под основной информации на странице. При запуске кода, у меня через отдельный поток, параллельно серверу, запускается функция, которая при выполнении действия должна добавлять виджет на страницу, без надобности перезагрузки страницы. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: [Flask soketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) вам в помощь.